# Evaluate variable assignments in a string for a list of variables

Tags: r, string, list, split, evaluation

How can I split the following string by each variable?

```
"(x=c(0,2), y=c(3,2), z= c(2,2))"
```

I want to evaluate those variables and extract them into a list. My desired output is identical to:

```
list(x=c(0,2), y=c(3,2), z=c(2,2))
```

Comment: @Whatif im trying to get each variable, x, y, z in the string separated

Comment: @Zheyuan Li The first one you mentioned should be the output. 
 list (x =c(0,2), y=c(3,2), z =c(2,2))

Answer (score 3):

Given a string:

```
string <- "(x=c(0,2), y=c(3,2), z= c(2,2))"
```

the simplest way to get your desired output is either of the following:

```
eval(parse(text = paste0("list", string)))
eval(str2lang(paste0("list", string)))  ## recommended

#$x
#[1] 0 2
#
#$y
#[1] 3 2
#
#$z
#[1] 2 2
```

Overuse of `eval` + `parse` is not recommended. But the procedure of turning text into evaluable **R** expression is parsing. There is really no way to avoid `parse` in this case (`str2lang` is just a a trimmed version of `parse`.)

Of course, if you show us how you obtained this string in the first place, then we may find out a better way than building and processing this string for the desired output.

---

**Similar Example**

Here is a similar Q & A: [Convert list of strings to list of expressions?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/73313007/4891738)

Comment: Thank you @Zheyuan Li. I tried the Eval parse but heard it’s bad for security reasons? Know of another approach?

Comment: @Jonathan A highly similar question was asked yesterday, and two answers there also use `eval` + `parse`. So there is nothing wrong with this approach. Are you able to accept my answer, by clicking the grey check mark? Cheers.

Comment: @Jonathan Another Q & A today: https://stackoverflow.com/a/73330914/4891738