# Convert list of strings to list of expressions?

Tags: r

In R, I have a list of strings that I would like to convert to a list of expressions. Is this at all possible? I have tried a few functions like eval() or parse() but they don't seem to do the trick. Here is an example below.

```
## What my list currently looks like
current = list(
  "A = c(0,1)",
  "B = c(0,2)"
)

## What I would like it to be
ideal = list(
  A = c(0,1),
  B = c(0,2)
)

> print(current)
[[1]]
[1] "A = c(0,1)"

[[2]]
[1] "B = c(0,2)"

> print(ideal)
$A
[1] 0.0 1.0

$B
[1] 0.0 2.0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We could `paste` and do an `eval`

```
eval(parse(text = paste("list(", toString(unlist(current)), ")")))
```

-output

```
$A
[1] 0 1

$B
[1] 0 2
```

---

Or get the `dput` and then use `eval/parse`

```
 eval(parse(text = gsub('"', '', capture.output(dput(current)))))
$A
[1] 0 1

$B
[1] 0 2
```

Answer (score 1):

You could solve your problem as follow:

```
eval(parse(text = sprintf("list(%s)", toString(current))))

$A
[1] 0 1

$B
[1] 0 2
```